# Eclipse JSF content assist not working

Tags: eclipse, jsf, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to work with an (existing) JSF Project in the current Eclipse (Kepler SR 1). Sadly Eclipse is ignoring the links between JSF/JSP pages and ManagedBeans (via faces-config.xml).
I cannot CTRL-Click on a `#{myBean.someValue}` (inside a tag attribute) and I dont get any autocompletion assist when i hit CTRL-Space inside `#{}`.

The project is using somewhat ancient library versions - maybe that is a problem?

- JavaEE 5
- Dynamic Web Module version 2.4
- JSF 1.1
- BEA WebLogic 10.0 as target runtime

I tried all the guides on stackoverflow and created a dummy project as described in the 
[JSF Tooling User Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/tutorial/JSFTools_tutorial.html) but none helped. Any help appretiated!

Comment: Do you have the JSF facet enabled? Anyway, I don't know if that's possible even with newest JSF versions, not at least for me. I get the link to the bean when crtl+click, but not autocompletion for its methods... (having declared them using annotations instead of xml).

Comment: The JSF facet is enabled. I tried disabling and enabling but that doesnt change anything.

Comment: I think autocompletion is not possible. You can achieve the ctrl-click utility but this will drive you to the faces-config reference, later on you'll have to click there on the managed bean's full qualified name and this will lead you to the java class. I find it more useful to know which class is already the assigned to the managed bean and going to it through type search.

Comment: Did you try install the jboss-tools plugin ?

Comment: I did not because the project is not using jboss - its a WebLogic setup. Should I nevertheless try ?

Comment: Try it, there is better content assist then in the plain XML editor. Never mind you doesnt use the jboss app server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem with Kepler and solved the problem by

1. installing JBoss Tools
2. Right clicking the project > Configure -> Add JSF capabilities

Hope that helps others, too.

Comment: I have never installed the JBoss tools as my scope moved on, but as the only answer and the positive feedback it deserves to be accepted :)

Comment: I had a clean install of Eclipse and forgot to install JBoss tools. While the Eclipse Enterprise Java Developer Tools seem to have shown some improvement, they fail all the way here

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall IceFaces plugin to get the autocomplete of JBoss Editor to work.

a kind of interference...

JSF 1.1
IceFaces 1.8 ( but without plugin)
Eclipse Mars